# How do I deploy Docker Swarm securely, without hard-coding everything?

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, docker-swarm

I would like to set up Docker Swarm over a public network, and I would like to minimize the amount of reconfiguration that has to happen when workers' IP addresses change. The [recommended setup](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/swarm/install-manual/) requires generating a TLS certificate for each server, but if I generate certificates for IP addresses, I'll have an ever-growing certificate "database".

[flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/README.md) looked promising, especially as it is used by Kubernetes and CoreOS, and it's already packaged in Fedora. Unfortunately, its [transport encryption support](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/pull/290) is not ready yet.

I also looked at [Weave](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/blob/master/README.md), but I was really sketched out by its [recommended setup](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave#installation) which involved curl-ing a binary off their site, and by their ["security"](http://docs.weave.works/weave/latest_release/features.html#security).

Is there some old-school solution that I should be looking at instead? An SDN competitor that I missed?

Comment: What's wrong with "an ever-growing certificate database"? It's how I'd do it.

Comment: It feels dirty and unnecessary. I feel like I should be able to get away with one server certificate and a multitude of client certificates. The workers should be cattle, not pets.

Comment: You can automate certificate issuance, you know...

Comment: If there's no better way, I would end up with an Ansible role that issues certificates. I don't like having to re-run a playbook whenever a machine gets a different IP, and I really don't like having a CA "database" file that will up with trash over time.

Comment: How often, and under what circumstances, are your IP addresses changing?  I'd expect they'd only change on container restart, which means you can hook into that and issue a new certificate if a new IP is involved.  You don't really end up with a "database" of certificates; you don't even need to keep any information on what's been issued in the CA at all if you don't want to (although a "properly run" CA *should*; it's a trivial amount of data to keep, anyway.